# Issue with image formatting with chrome (CSS)

Tags: css, image, google-chrome, image-size

I'm having an issue with Google Chrome with my new website, I am designing an iPhone out of different images, the issue I am having is with all other browsers the code loads fine and the iPhone displays correctly, however with Chrome it seems to for some reason enlarge the image to the point that it is slightly blurry and it also moved the image about 1px to the left making it obvious to the end user that the iPhone is in separate pieces.

HTML Code

```
<!-- Copyright 2012 Ben Green -->
<!-- v1.1a Just iStuff -->
<!-- Not to be reproduced without permission -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Just iStuff</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="layout">
    <div id="iphone-holder">
        <div id="iphone-top">
        </div>
        <div id="iphone-left">
        </div>
        <div id="iphone-content">            
            <div id="home-top-alternate2">
            </div>
            <div id="button-top">
            </div>
            <div id="button-left">
            </div>
            <div id="icon-row-holder">

                    </div> <!-- icon row holder -->
                </div>
            <div id="button-right">
            </div>
        <div id="iphone-right">
        </div>
        <div id="iphone-bottom">
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code

```
    #iphone-top {
    width:461px;
    height:123px;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(images/iphonetop.png);
}

#iphone-left {
    width:94px;
    height:413px;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(images/iphoneleft.png);
}

#iphone-content {
    width: 274px;
    height: 413px;
    float: left;
    background: url(images/wallpaper.png) no-repeat;
}

#iphone-right {
    width: 93px;
    height:413px;
    float: left;
    background: url(images/iphoneright.png) no-repeat;
}

#iphone-bottom {
    width:461px;
    height:225px;
    background-image: url(images/iphonebottom.png);
    float: left;
}

#iphone-holder {
    width: 461px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w5a5f

Using Chrome: 
http://img851.imageshack.us/img851/7237/iphone1q.png 

Using Safari: 
http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/5482/iphone2t.png

Jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/w5a5f

Firefox & Safari display it properly but Chrome fails to, do I need some specific chrome CSS to stop it from enlarging it or is there a fix for this?

UPDATE: It would seem that once uploaded to a server this issue disappears, so it only occurs on a local file...

Comment: Care to add both codes to a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? :)

Comment: I can't help but notice that you didn't post the things you have problems with, the images themselves.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w5a5f/

My apologies one second I shall post them :)

Comment: @MrLister Image uploaders are out there too.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w5a5f/1/ This jsfiddle contains all code and correct links to the images :)

Comment: Direct link to the album:
http://imageshack.us/g/401/iphonebottom.png/

Comment: Hmm I tested it in chrome and it looks fine for me.

Comment: Hmm really? Interesting, I shall try it using a different computer

Comment: Does chrome autosize per screen size? so say increase the size based on the screen width and height?

Were you viewing from the jsfiddle or did you compile the code yourself?

Answer (score 0):

The code you uploaded at jsfiddle is fine with both Chrome and Firefox and displaying same iphone layout! I tested it on my system!

Comment: Hmm interesting, so you compiled your code the same or you just viewed using jsfiddle? for me it displays fine in jsfiddle but when i view from my own index.html file it enlarges it to extreme proportions

Comment: Using Chrome:
http://img851.imageshack.us/img851/7237/iphone1q.png
Using Safari:
http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/5482/iphone2t.png

Comment: On my system:
Chrome: http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/348/1chrome.png
Firefox: http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/5743/2firefox.png

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not zoomed in with Chrome. When you zoom in, you do get the 1 pixel difference that your screenshot shows.